# Can't make a resizable / draggable <textarea>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/TdaHH/4/) - where I'm trying to create a textarea that is both draggable and resizable, but the `draggable()` and `resizable()` methods aren't doing it. If I just replace `<textarea>` in the ninth line below with `<div>` it works fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

```
 $(function () {
   $('#new').click(function () {
     var new_offset = {
       top: 30,
       left: 40
     };
     var new_width = 200;
     var new_height = 150;
     var newElement$ = $('<textarea>')
       .width(new_width)
       .height(new_height)
       .draggable()
       .resizable()
       .css({
         'position': 'absolute',
         'background-color': 'yellow',
         'border-color': 'black',
         'border-width': '1px',
         'border-style': 'solid'
       })
       .offset(new_offset)
       .appendTo('body');
   });
 });
```

Comment: well out of the blue i guess u have to prevent default behaviour since a textarea is made by default on click to focus and what not, and on top of that you could remove the .resizeable since by default most browsers already has that ability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that will allow dragging and text editing.  However, you cannot use your cursor to select text.  You can shift-arrow key or cmd-A though.

Essentially, you surround the textarea in a DIV, remove resize from textarea, and make the div resizable and draggable.

Here is the jQuery you must add to the draggable() function.

```
.draggable({
    cancel: "text",
    start: function (){
        $('#textarea').focus();
    },
    stop: function (){
        $('#textarea').focus();
    } 
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TdaHH/5/)