# How to trigger parent drag event when child is dragged in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am having trouble with the textarea element. I am creating a div (parent) dynamically and then append to that parent-div a textarea element with the same size of the parent. When the user attempts to drag the textarea I would like to drag the parent (which contains the textarea) instead. I've tried the `handle` option but that doesn't seem to work with the textarea element.

Basically this is what I have (except it is created dynamically):

```
<div class="floatingPanel"> 
    <textarea class="dragger">
        Drag from here
    </textarea>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.floatingPanel').draggable({
        handle: '.dragger'
    });
});
```

I found a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaver/W42Yt/3/) that was very similar to my problem. I modified it for the textarea element.

What's interesting is that when the textarea is changed to div, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy here has a solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819346

You can not use text area as draggable because it is restricted. In the [jQuery API](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) it is noted that 'it prevents dragging starting on `"input,textarea,button,select,option"` elements. '. Having said that, if there is a way to modify this functionality then I am not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately that didn't work either. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W42Yt/5/

Comment: Your Fiddle works...


1. You need to include jquery-ui for draggable to work.
2. Fix coding errros.

Check this--  http://jsfiddle.net/W42Yt/6/

Comment: Thank you Nis, it works this time. I wasn't aware of the external resources in fiddle. This was my very first fiddle. Sorry for my beginner-mistake.